# c# Quiero convertir una tabla dentada de caracteres en una tabla dentada de enteros

Tags: c#, array-bidimensional

Soy novato en la programación en c# y estoy tratando de convertir una tabla dentada de caracteres en una tabla dentada de números enteros. De momento he llegado hasta aquí pero no he podido avanzar más. Gracias!!

```
string[] paisesString = new string[20] 
                {"España", "Rusia", "Francia", "Belgica", "Portugal","Reino Unido", "Italia", "Alemania",
                "Malta", "Chipre", "Polonia", "Hungria", "Austria", "Croacia", "Bosnia", "Serbia", "Grecia",
                "Albania", "Ucrania", "Georgia"};

        char[][] paises = new char[20][];

        for (int i = 0; i < paises.Length; i++)
        {
            paises[i] = paisesString[i].ToCharArray();
        }

        
        int[][] numeroPais = new int[20][];
        
        for (int j = 0; j < paises.Length; j++)
        {
        
            numeroPais[j] = new int[j];
        
            for (int k = 0; k < paises[j].Length; k++ )
            {
                numeroPais[j][k] = (char)(paises[j][k]);
                Console.WriteLine(numeroPais[j][k]);
            }
        }
```

Y yo quiero esto Console.Writeline(numeroPais[0]);
y que salga por pantalla algo así:
821240567069

Comment: POn un ejemplo de lo que quieres decir, aclara mas tu duda

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que es una tabla dentada? y cual es el problema con tu codigo? que cosa no hace?

Comment: Lo que quiero es de lo que hay dentro del char[][] me aparezcan números de la tabla ASCII para luego ordenarlo en orden alfabético. Se que tengo que hacer un ToLower pero con eso no tengo problema. Lo que tengo problema es pasarlo a números cada caracter.

Comment: O sea tu lo que quieres es transformar cada caracter a equivalente en codigo ASCII?, pon un ejemplo de como quedaria Portugal para entenderte mejor

Comment: Si, eso es lo que pretendo. No se como quedaría Portugal en ASCII porque no se hacerlo.....

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] paisesString = new string[20] 
                {"España", "Rusia", "Francia", "Belgica", "Portugal","Reino Unido", "Italia", "Alemania",
                "Malta", "Chipre", "Polonia", "Hungria", "Austria", "Croacia", "Bosnia", "Serbia", "Grecia",
                "Albania", "Ucrania", "Georgia"};

    char[][] paises = new char[20][];

    for (int i = 0; i < paises.Length; i++)
    {
        paises[i] = paisesString[i].ToCharArray();
    }

    char[][] paisesLetraPequeña = new char[20][]
    int[][] numeroPais = new int[20][];
    
    for (int j = 0; j < paises.Length; j++)
    {
        paisesLetraPequeña[j] = new char[paises[j].Length];
        numeroPais[j] = new int [paises[j].Length];
    
        for (int k = 0; k < paises[j].Length; k++ )
        {
            paisesLetraPequeña[j][k] = char.ToLower(paises[j][k]);
            numeroPais[j][k] = (int) paisesLetraPequeña[j][k]);
            Console.WriteLine(numeroPais[j][k]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Finalmente se me encendió la bombilla y lo pude solucionar.